# Updating Number of Neurons in a Keras Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a callback to dynamically "split" the number of neurons in a network at the end of each epoch. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to update the layer size. Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Model / data parameters
num_classes = 10
num_neurons = 32
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.summary()
modellayers=model.layers
c=0
for l in modellayers:
    if c==1:
        l.output_shape=[None,64]
    if c==2:
        l.input_shape=[None,64]
    print(str(c),l.input)
    print(str(c),l.output)
    c+=1
```

This gives back the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "output_shape", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

If I print the shapes I get back:

```
0 Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)
0 Tensor("flatten/Reshape:0", shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32)
1 Tensor("flatten/Reshape:0", shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32)
1 Tensor("dense/Relu:0", shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)
2 Tensor("dense/Relu:0", shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)
2 Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
```

I see they are Tensors, so I've also tried set_shape, but that didn't work either. Basically, I want to know how to update the number of neurons in a layer object.

P.S. I'm not having difficulty in splitting weights and biases and transferring those to a new working model, as can be seen in the example here: https://jjohnson-777.medium.com/machine-learning-granularity-by-splitting-neurons-fd2f02e07817. But now I would like to develop a callback function to do this on the fly between epochs.

Comment: maybe it would be easier if you would overwrite the model with a new model with changed number of neurons and initialise it with the weights/bias you split?

Comment: @luigigi - that's what I did in the working example in the P.S. at the end. But I need to be able to modify the model attributes during a training run so I can dynamically update the number of neurons. I intend to split the neurons (their weights and biases) between epochs based on those neurons exhibiting the most loss. A callback should be able to do it, but I need to know how to change the object attributes within the callback(i.e. same model).

Comment: in pytorch you could change the existing layers between the epochs because you define what you want to do during training loop instead of using a `fit` function. maybe keras isn't the way to go here

Comment: That's good to know. I'll check out Pytorch.